# Salesforce Lightning Quick Actions in Lightning Calendar

Tags: lightning-experience, event

Is it possible to add salesforce lightning quick actions in Lightning Experience Calendar Section.

- There is a lightning component **`c:SomeQuickAction`**, it implements **"force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId"**
- I have created a lightning quick action for this component and I have added it to the page layout of Event Object under salesforce1 and lightning experience actions.

Yet I am not able to see this quick action in the Salesforce Lightning Experience Calendars for Events ? Is there any other configurations apart from this ?

Comment: Try implementing force:lightningQuickAction.

Comment: Tried it already, Makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible atleast in the current release. Though the calendar layout is associated with event , the layout is not actually same for both the event and calendar standard component in lightning experience. Hence it could be a limitation as of now. For now you might have to go ahead with a custom calendar of your own or try an alternate approach like global actions ( though it would not suit most use case scenarios at least it did not suit me ).

As I too faced a similar issue of this kind. Hence I have posted​ a new idea in Salesforce idea exchange for quick actions on calendar component in lightning experience . Hope Salesforce delivers it  in the near future until then we will have to make due without object specific lightning quick actions on calendar layouts​.

Idea exchange Link : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cOaLQAU

Comment: I think you might be right. I have exhausted my options here as well. Thank you confirming the same.

Comment: Also, you can comment on their GitHub issue tracker here: https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues

Comment: I thought this link dealt only with slds ux designs & it's issues .. the one that we are experiencing is more of a feature request ( Salesforce functionality rather than UX ).